# how does the repository path is set when creating a nw SVN repository using Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn

I wanted to is there a way to find how the path of a newly created SVN repository is set when we use tortoise SVN to create a new repository. As Tortoise SVN tool asks only for a repository name before creation then how is the path of the repository set. IS there a way to define or choose the path before creating a repository?

Comment: Use Windows Explorer to create a new folder where you want the repository to be. Right-click that folder in Explorer, choose the TortoiseSVN menu, and then choose *Create repository here...*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're on a Windows server?  I haven't use TortoiseSVN to create a repository (we host ours on Linux), but according to the [documentation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html), it gets created in the current directory.  The command seems to be "Create repository here", which would imply that it puts in the current directory.

Most SVN admins just use the command-line tool "svnadmin" (which can be installed if you add the command line tools during TortoiseSVN installation).  That always creates the repository in the current directory (unless you give an absolute path).  In which case you can just:

```
C:> cd \SVN
C:> svnadmin create REPONAME
```

Which would put your repo at C:\SVN\REPONAME.